# Limit of the ratio of the logs, knowing the ratio

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider $f,g: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^+$ and suppose that $\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=+\infty$.

Can anything be proved (equality or inequality) in general about $\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log f(x)}{\log g(x)}$? If not, which additional (minimal) hypotheses could be added to say something meaninful about this liminf?

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=x^a$ and $g(x)=x^b$, then if $a>b$ the first limit is $\infty$ but the second limit will be $a/b$ - this we can achieve any positive value for the second limit.  If $f(x)=e^x$ and $g(x)=x$ then both limits are $\infty$.

Comment: Thanks Apollo for your examples. But then, is it always true that $\liminf_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \geq \liminf_{x\to \infty} \frac{ \log f(x)}{\log g(x)}$?

Comment: Not necessarily: consider $f(x)=x^a$, $g(x)=x^b$ with $a<b$.  Then the first limit is zero but the second limit is again $a/b$ which gives us any positive value $<1$...

Comment: I'd be surprised if you could say much about the relationship between the two ratios in general.

Comment: Ale You might want to summarize the content of the comments and to post the result as an answer, to be accepted later on after a while, if only to avoid leaving the question in disarray.